# LinqPad Syntax for adding foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, linqpad

This is the SQL I used in LinqPad:

```
CREATE TABLE Category 
(
    catID int NOT NULL,
    catName NVARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    catDesc NVARCHAR(150) NULL,
    catCount int NOT NULL ,
    CONSTRAINT category_pk PRIMARY KEY (catID)
);

CREATE TABLE InventoryTBLC 
(
    itemID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT PK_items PRIMARY KEY,
    itemName NVARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    itemDesc NVARCHAR(150) NULL,
    itemQuantity int,
    itemPrice int,
    imagePath NVARCHAR(300),
    correctInsert NVARCHAR(300),
    realImage image,

    CONSTRAINT FK_category FOREIGN KEY (catID) REFERENCES Category(catID)   
);
```

But I get the following error:

> Invalid column ID. [ catID ]

Can someone help me with the LinqPad syntax?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a column as the foreign key, you have to **list** that column in your table definition first! Adding the foreign key constraint does **NOT** add that column to your table!

And this is in no way Linqpad specific - this is **standard SQL** behavior.

So either you need to add `catId` to your second table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE InventoryTBLC 
(
    itemID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT PK_items PRIMARY KEY,
    itemName NVARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    itemDesc NVARCHAR(150) NULL,
    itemQuantity int,
    itemPrice int,
    imagePath NVARCHAR(300),
    correctInsert NVARCHAR(300),
    realImage image,
    catID int NOT NULL,   -- this column *MUST* exist to be used as FK

    CONSTRAINT FK_category 
        FOREIGN KEY (catID) REFERENCES Category(catID)   
);
```

or then maybe you want to use one of the other pre-existing columns in `InventoryTBLC` as your FK column?

Comment: @deelliieeD: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.